# Swift and Firebase Database - Missing argument label 'andPriority' in call

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The code below is being used to update my firebase database when a user registers in the app, it is suppose to authenticate the user in the database and also save a boolean value. I get the following error when this is implemented (see below).

```
@IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailEntryField.text!, password: passwordEntryField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {

                //Show SVProgressHUD
                SVProgressHUD.show()

                //save User to Database
                let newUserInfo : [String:Any] = ["email":self.emailEntryField.text!, "state":true]
                self.ref.child("users").child(user?.user.uid).setValue(newUserInfo, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    print("New User Saved")
                }

                //Dismiss SVProgressHUD
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                //move to info view controller
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToInfo", sender: self)

            } else {

                print("Signup Unsuccessul")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing **)**  after the block

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user?.user.uid).setValue(newUserInfo, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
  print("New User Saved")
}
```

Add ) at the end, like this

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user?.user.uid).setValue: newUserInfo, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
  print("New User Saved")
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It always seems to be something so simple...thank you for your help